# how to create an exception inside a flutter for loop

Tags: flutter

I need the items inside a for to have an action with the exception of the last one, which will have a different action

an example that DOESN'T WORK:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  print('1 - 9');


  if (i.last) {
    print('last item');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put method in the condition part of the for loop. Here is such example:

```dart
void main() {
  const limit = 10;
  for(int i =0 ;
      () {
        if(i < limit && i < limit-1) {
          doActionA(i);
          return true;
        }
        else if(i < limit){
          doActionB(i);
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }()
      
      ; i++);
}

void doActionA(int i){
  print('Not last $i');
}

void doActionB(int i) {
  print('last $i');
}
```

output

```
Not last 0
Not last 1
Not last 2
Not last 3
Not last 4
Not last 5
Not last 6
Not last 7
Not last 8
last 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  print('0 - 8');

  if (i == 9) {
    print('last item');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 print('1 - 9');


 if (i==9) {
    print('last item');
    throw Exception("Your message");
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible, you can just paste the snippet in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev)  and play with it

```
void main() {
  try {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (i == 3) {
        print('item $i');
        throw 'customError';
      } else {
        print('item $i');
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (e == 'customError') {
      print('You caught your custom error \n $e');
    } else {
      print('You caught some other error');
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that will help